# Reusing Eclipse Console Scroll Lock

Tags: eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface, rcp

I am trying to reuse the Scroll Lock feature on the Console view in Eclipse in a different view. I want to contribute an action (to do the scroll lock function) not on view toolbar but on the toolbar container e.g. see where the `ScrollLock` function is in the console view - it is NOT on the toolbar of the view but in the actual frame header that houses the console view. These actions change then depending what view you have selected. I want to know HOW DO I CONTRIBUTE AN ACTION TO THIS PART. So far all tutorials contribute toolbar items to toolbars inside the `ViewPart`. I want to keep the same look and feel as the console view.

Comment: That is the view toolbar. When the view is show in a part stack the toolbar is moved up in to the header if there is space.

Comment: Hi my toolbar contribution appears on the toolbar inside the view regardless. I am using toolbarPath: "additions" ?

Comment: Sorry - I got it sorted. I was just adding the eclipse Command and giving it a PUSH style. I replaced with a ViewAction. Cheers - Ant